# What's Linux test -a command test for?

Tags: linux, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

Please take a look at the following code,

```
snap=snapshot.file   
touch snapshot.file-1

$ [ -a $snap-1 ] && echo yes 
yes
```

What does the `test -a` command tests for here?

I tried `info coreutils 'test invocation'` and searched for `-a`, but didn't find it in the *file characteristic tests* section, but rather in the *connectives for test* section.

Is such `test -a` command an undocumented one?

Answer (score 1):

`-a` is used for an `and` expression. You would usually use it with two operands:

```
$[ $snap0 -a $snap1 ]
```

not sure what context it is used in here, but it's possible that someone removed the first operand without removing the `-a` operator.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said I found it **in the connectives for test section**. But NO, you are wrong. Try it out and you will see.

Comment: This is bash? Why does your tag say `linux` when you are using OS X coreutils?

Comment: Use `man test` and check out the **2nd last line**.  BTW, my `man test` says **GNU coreutils 8.20 October 2012 TEST(1)**. Yes, This is bash.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: I've said that it's bash shell -- `$ echo $SHELL  
/bin/bash  `
Do you understand the posted code? Have you tried the code for yourself already?

Comment: Yes - it's invalid on my system with bash